# An element of a pointer vector of object pointers assignment

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector, variable-assignment

I'm having trouble assigning an element of a pointer vector of object pointers to an object pointer. I'm on a Linux and using Eclipse IDE. If you want to take a look at my problem:

```
void Parse::parseDatalogProgram(vector<Token*>* tokens)
{
    Token* currentToken = tokens[0];
...
}
```

I'm getting a syntax error saying "cannot convert ‘std::vector’ to ‘Token*’ in initialization", although above doesn't seem to look that way How do I properly fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tokens` is a pointer, not a `vector` itself. You can do

```
tokens->operator[](0);
```

or

```
(*tokens)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Token* currentToken = (*tokens)[0];
```

Make sure tokens is not null. Why don't you pass a reference, instead?

Answer (score 2):

`tokens` is a **pointer to vector**, not the object or a reference. The C++ way would be changing the function prototype to:

```
void Parse::parseDatalogProgram(const vector<Token*>& tokens){...}
```

If that is not possible, you can simply dereference the pointer before using it: `Token* currentToken = (*tokens)[0]`